# How to pass checkbox value to controller

Tags: spring, jsp

I want to order(buy) those items which are select in a shopping cart. I uses check box for this but getting confuse how to pass it in **order now** href.

I want to order all item only one time click.

check  this url : /id=${items.id}">Order Now!

**cart.jsp**

```
      <form action="">
        <c:forEach items="${listCart}" var="items">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="${items.id}"/></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">${items.id}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">${items.name}</td>

            </c:forEach>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
        <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl" href="<c:url value="/order"/>/id=${items.id}">Order Now!</a>
            </div>
            </div>
       </div>
     </form>
```

**controller.jsp**

```
    @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/order/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createOrder(@PathVariable int id) {
    customerOrderModel customerOrder = new customerOrderModel();
    Cart cart = cartdao.getCartByID(id);
    customerOrder.setCart(cart);

    CustomerModel customer = cart.getCustomer();
    customerOrder.setCustomerID(customer);
    customerOrder.setBillingAddress(customer.getBillingAddress());
    customerOrder.setShippingAddress(customer.getShippingAddress());

    orderDao.addCustomerOrder(customerOrder);

    return "redirect:/view/cart/addItem";

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a SpringMVC Form to submit, or an Ajax call?

1) **Option1 : submit to the server with a SpringMVC Form.** In this case, follow
https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/ . Your Form needs to specify where it's going to go, and how its fields will be mapped to your Data Bean class (with `path`). You will be using SpringMVC Form tags, e.g.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="/order">
    ...
    <form:input path="name" type="text" /> <!-- same for checkboxes or other controls -->
    ...
</form:form>
```

2) **Option2 : use Ajax to submit:** use JS on the Client Side to get selections that you need:

```
var selections = [];

// Find all selected checkboxes and store their values in an array
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index) {
    selections.push($(this).val());
});

// Now call Ajax and pass this array of selections to whatever receives it in SpringMVC...

$.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        url : '/order',   
        data : JSON.stringify({'selections' : selections})
});
```